# Increase salary tax every 5000

Tags: c#

I have fixed taxes for salaries that increase by 900 every 5000.

For example:

- Salaries from 50000 to 54999, the tax will be 4400
- Salaries from 55000 to 59999, the tax will increase by 900, so it will be 5300
- Salaries from 60000 to 64999, the tax will increase by 900, so it will be 6200

I have a long list of salaries.

I am new to C# and I managed to go through this by using if statement.

```
if(salaryyy < 50000)
{
    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
}
else if (salaryyy > 49999 && salaryyy < 55000)
{
    int result;
    //int rate = 900;
    int tax = 4400;

    result = salaryyy - 4400;

    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(tax);
}
else if(salaryyy > 54999 && salaryyy < 60000)
{
    int result;
    //int rate = 900;
    int tax = 5300;

    result = salaryyy - 5300;

    textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(tax);
}
```

I want textbox2 to show the tax rate.

I don't think this is a good way because I might end up writing a really long code.

Is there any easy way I can get around this?

Comment: Those are called "bands" or "brackets". Plenty of results if you search on that. The most common approach is to declare a list of bands with their accompanying percentage, then walk over the bands and apply each to the remainder of the previous band.

Comment: Don't use different limits for each bracket. What happens now if it's 55000? It also makes things harder to read

Comment: You work for the tax-man and want help? hahahaha :D

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if it is 55000 tax will be 5300

Comment: @TimSchmelter my bad, mistyping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following calculation using integer division to get the factor:

```
decimal salary = 55000;
decimal startingTax = 4400;
int taxRelevant = (int) (salary - 50000);
decimal tax = 0;
if(taxRelevant >= 0)
    tax = startingTax + (taxRelevant / 5000) * 900;
```

This assumes that under 50k salary you dont have to pay taxes and that it increases linearly.